# Behat fill form fields which are dynamically set to 'visible'

Tags: javascript, symfony, selenium, behat

I have a form with hidden fields. If a user selects a checkbox then some of the hidden form fields are revealed using the jquery function [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). It's very straight forward code, you can view an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfh2sLxy/2/).

My problem is that Behat still considers the form fields to be invisible and non-interactable after the checkbox has revealed them for the user.

This is the scenario I'm trying to test in my feature:

```
When I check "form_checkbox" 
And I fill in "form_field" with "some data"
```

How do I go about waiting for the on click listener for the checkbox to finish execution before I attempt to fill in the form or is there a better approach?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting an `AfterStep` step between the two to allow for jQuery to perform the animation. Something like this in your FeatureContext should help:

```
 /**
 * @AfterStep @javascript
 */
public function afterStep($event)
{
    $text = $event->getStep()->getText();
    if (preg_match('/(follow|press|click|submit|check)/i', $text)) {
        $this->jqueryWait();
    }
}

protected function jqueryWait($duration = 4000)
{
        $this->getSession()->wait($duration, '(0 === jQuery.active && 0 === jQuery(':animated').length)');
}
```

This basically means that after any step whose text contains "follow", "press", "click", "submit" or "check", the execution will wait either `$duration` milliseconds or until the javascript assertion returns `true` (i.e. jQuery is not animating anything).